# how to bring a 3rd table to a JsonResult and how to write it in my controller Details?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

my second join me out of error and I do not see how else I can write it

[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetBadgesStudentList (int CohortProgramEnrollmentID)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

```
    var badgesList =
        from bad in db.BadgeAssignments
        join coh in db.CohortProgramEnrollment on bad.CohortProgramEnrollmentID equals coh.CohortSubscriptionId
        join des in db.Badges on bad.BadgeID equals des.Description
        where bad.BadgeID == CohortProgramEnrollmentID
        select new { Badges = des };

    return Json(badgesList.ToList().Select(x => new { 
         x.Badges.CohortProgramEnrollmentID, x.Badges.Description }),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
// GET: CohortSubscriptions/Details/5 
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Coach")] 
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{ 
if (id == null) { 
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); } CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions = db.CohortSubscriptions.Find(id); 
if (cohortSubscriptions == null)
{
 return HttpNotFound(); 
}
 return View(cohortSubscriptions); 
}
```

I want to get the badges in the table Badges that are connected to the specific Student (by CohortSubscriptionsId). 
To get there I need 3 tables:
 in the table Badges I have my badge ID which gives me his description, 
 in the BadgeAssigments table I have my BadgeID that is connected with the 
    CohortProgramEnrollmentID and 
 in the CohortProgramEnrollments table I have the ID that is finally connected with the Student: CohortSubscriptionId

Comment: what is your problem here ?

Comment: my 2nd join me out of error and I do not see how else I can write it

Comment: the type of one of the join clause is incorrect. type inteference failed ine the call to 'Join'

Comment: is it syntax error or compilation ?

Comment: Synthax for now

Comment: is 'des.Description' is the primary key of the table badge?

Comment: No is ID who becomes BadgeID in the other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the join order is correct but the equality clauses are somehow confusing, i think this line compares two different keys :

```
bad.BadgeID equals des.Description
```

So i guess the correct join will be something like that as yu compare keys and IDs.

```
 var badgesList =
            from bad in db.BadgeAssignments
            join coh in db.CohortProgramEnrollment on bad.CohortProgramEnrollmentID equals coh.ID
            join des in db.Badges on bad.BadgeID equals des.ID
            where bad.BadgeID == CohortProgramEnrollmentID
            select new { Badges = des };

        return Json(badgesList.ToList().Select(x => new { 
             x.Badges.CohortProgramEnrollmentID, x.Badges.Description }),
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: yes thank you my 2nd join is correct now, 
it gave me another error that I just fixed, remains to see if it compiles

Comment: now how do I write this in my Script so that the list of Bages connected to the students come out in full, this is the first time I do it other than in a DropDownList

Comment: Sorry, in my controller rather

Comment: // GET: CohortSubscriptions/Details/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Coach")]
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            CohortSubscriptions cohortSubscriptions = db.CohortSubscriptions.Find(id);
            if (cohortSubscriptions == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(cohortSubscriptions);
        }

Comment: you can check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/)  it will help you in binding data from controller to dropDownList